# What means bash ${id:0:1} expression

Tags: bash, shell, sh

What means bash ${id:0:1} expression?

Example of use:

```
wget -qc http://$host/image_${id:0:1}/$id/image.png -O ../../../folder
```

$id = number (1-8 digits)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a substring starting at index 0 (first character) and having length 1.  So, it's the first character of the value of `$id`; if, for example, `$id` were `54321`, then `${id:0:1}` would be `5`.

See all the available special parameter expansions [in the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).